# Getting task by name from taskqueue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

How can I get a task by name?

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
taskqueue.add(name='foobar', url='/some-handler', params={'foo': 'bar'}

task_queue = taskqueue.Queue('default')
task_queue.delete_tasks_by_name('foobar') # would work

# looking for a method like this:
foobar_task = task_queue.get_task_by_name('foobar')
```

It should be possible with the REST API (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest/tasks/get). But I would prefer something like `task_queue.get_task_by_name('foobar')`. Any ideas? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the task with this name exists - it may have been already executed. And even if you manage to `get` a task, it may be executed while you are trying to do something with it. So when you try to put it back, you have no idea if you are adding it for the first time or for the second time.

Because of this uncertainty, I can't see any use case where getting a task by name may be useful.

EDIT:

You can give a name to your task in order to ensure that a particular task only executes once. When you add a task with a name to a queue, App Engine will check if the task with such name already exists. If it does, the subsequent attempt will fail.

For example, you can have many instances running, and each instance may need to insert an entity in the Datastore. Your first option is to check if an entity already exists in a datastore. This is a relatively slow operation, and by the time you received your response (entity does not exist) and decide to insert it, another instance could have already inserted it. So you end up with two entities instead of one.

Your second option is to use tasks. Instead of inserting a new entity directly into a datastore, an instance creates a task to insert it, and it gives this task a name. If another instance tries to add a task with the same name, it will simply override the existing task. As a result, you are guaranteed that an entity will be inserted only once.

Comment: good point. what about a simple ``task_queue.task_exists('foobar')``?

Comment: Same story. By the time you have "it does exist" response, it may not exist anymore. Just like a Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see what is wrong about asking if the task exists at the time of asking for it?

Comment: Because the response is meaningless! You ask, a response arrives 50ms later (for example). But it's possible that a task was executed 2ms after the response "It exists" was sent to you. So by the time the response "It exists" arrives to you, the task does not exist anymore.

Comment: If there are retries, the task could exist for quite a long time.

Comment: Yes, but you don't know that. And there is no way to find out with any certainty.

Comment: "When you add a task with a name to a queue, App Engine will check if the task with such name already exists. If it does, it will be replaced with the new task." this is incorrect according to the docs - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/#PHP_Task_names

Comment: It looks like the documentation has changed since I added my response, so I updated it.

Comment: If you hover over the word "guarantee" in the docs here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#naming_a_task you will see it say `In very rare cases, a duplicate add can succeed.` - so even with your strategy, it seems it could create two entities. A note here also says they could retry and thus should be idempotent: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#timeouts